# Highcharts x axis date format issues

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to build a stacked bar with highcharts. I have some issues regarding the date time format on x axis. see here: http://jsfiddle.net/9y2gnnLy/

I want to add to the x axis an interval of 6 months - which begins with the smallest date and ends with the highest. In addition I want to calculate the duration in tooltip. For example the difference between tow dates: current expiring date - retired date = duration. How can I access the retired date on x axis?

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Microsoft Office 2010', 'Microsoft Office 2013', 'Microsoft Office 365']
    },
    yAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %Y', this.value);
            },
        }
            },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return  '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' + '<b>' + this.x +': </b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %Y',
                                          new Date(this.y)) + " - "
                + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %Y',
                                          new Date("Retired Date - How to access the retired date on x axis")) + '<br/><br/><b>Duration: </b>';
            }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Retired',
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
        data: [Date.parse("1/2/2013"), Date.parse("2/3/2014"), Date.parse("3/4/2015")],
        dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           format: '{series.name}'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Expiring',
        data: [Date.parse("1/2/2012"), Date.parse("6/3/2013"), Date.parse("8/4/2014")], 
        dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           format: "{series.name}"
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Standard',
        data: [Date.parse("1/2/2011"), Date.parse("5/3/2012"), Date.parse("4/4/2013")],
        dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           format: "{series.name}"
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Planning',
        color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
        data: [Date.parse("1/2/2010"), Date.parse("9/3/2011"), Date.parse("5/4/2012")],
        dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           format: '{series.name}'
        }
    }]
});
});
```

Is it possible to group like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jUiW.png)?

Comment: Have you considered using columnrange type of your series. With this type of series it will be much simpler to make what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/oamads2y/1/ If it will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to eliminate the space between the stacked bars? And to group the categories for example: Year - May, June, July?

Comment: You can change ranges in your bars, so they will not be stacked. You can use grouped categories plugin for adding more category levels: http://jsfiddle.net/oamads2y/3/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for:) The last question: how can I add data Labels to series (eg. series. name). I tried here: http://jsfiddle.net/ttrtb6xt/ but its not working - every bar should have one centered label. How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is what I used: plotOptions: {
    series: {
      grouping: false,
      stacking: 'normal',
      pointPadding: 0.0,
      allowPointSelect: true,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'center',
        x: -10,
        formatter: function() {
          return this.series.name;
        }
      }
    }
  },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use columnrange type of your series. With this type of series it will be much simpler to make the chart that you want to have.

You can set ranges in your bars, so they will look like they are stacked. You can use grouped categories plugin for adding more category levels
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

```
series: [{
  name: '1',
  data: [
    [Date.UTC(2011, 01, 01), Date.UTC(2011, 02, 01)],
    [Date.UTC(2011, 01, 02), Date.UTC(2011, 03, 01)],
    [Date.UTC(2011, 01, 01), Date.UTC(2011, 06, 01)]
  ],
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    format: "{series.name}"
  }
}, {
  name: '2',
  data: [
    [Date.UTC(2011, 02, 01), Date.UTC(2011, 03, 01)],
    [Date.UTC(2011, 03, 01), Date.UTC(2011, 10, 01)],
    [Date.UTC(2011, 06, 01), Date.UTC(2011, 08, 01)]
  ],
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    format: "{series.name}"
  }
}]
```

You can move your dataLabels to center of your bar using align: 'center' paramter:

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  align: 'center',
  formatter: function() {
    return this.series.name;
  }
}
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ttrtb6xt/1/

Comment: You can also add new xAxis for new category type: http://jsfiddle.net/3c5k2got/ If my examples have met your requirements, please mark my answer as correct

Comment: But it only works in bar type charts. Whats about coulmnrange type?

Comment: You can do something similar with columnrange type: http://jsfiddle.net/3c5k2got/1/

Comment: In my case it will not work, because I will have hundreds of grouped categories and to work with height in xAxis will make no sence. Thanks anyway.